# Azure Databricks writing a file into Azure Data Lake Gen 2

Tags: scala, azure, azure-data-lake, databricks, azure-databricks

I have an Azure Data Lake gen1 and an Azure Data Lake gen2 (Blob Storage w/hierarchical) and I am trying to create a Databricks notebook (Scala) that reads 2 files and writes a new file back into the Data Lake.  In both Gen1 and Gen2 I am experiencing the same issue where the file name of the output csv I have specified is getting saved as a directory and inside that directory it's writing 4 files "*committed*, *started*, _SUCCESS, and part-00000-tid-

[image: databricks output screenshot]

For the life of me, I can't figure out why it's doing it and not actually saving the csv to the location.
Here's an example of the code I've written.  If I do a .show() on the df_join dataframe then it outputs the correct looking results.  But the .write is not working correctly.

```
val df_names = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/mnt/datalake/raw/names.csv")
val df_addresses = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/mnt/datalake/raw/addresses.csv")

val df_join = df_names.join(df_addresses, df_names.col("pk") === df_addresses.col("namepk"))


df_join.write
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.mode("overwrite")
.save("/mnt/datalake/reports/testoutput.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it's creating a directory with multiple files, is because each partition is saved and written to the data lake individually. To save a single output file you need to re partition your dataframe

Let's use the dataframe API

```
confKey = "fs.azure.account.key.srcAcctName.blob.core.windows.net"
secretKey = "==" #your secret key
spark.conf.set(confKey,secretKey)
blobUrl = 'wasbs://MyContainerName@srcAcctName.blob.core.windows.net'
```

Coalesce your dataframe

```
df_join.coalesce(1)
.write
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.mode("overwrite")
.save("blobUrl" + "/reports/")
```

Change the file name

```
files = dbutils.fs.ls(blobUrl + '/reports/')
output_file = [x for x in files if x.name.startswith("part-")]
dbutils.fs.mv(output_file[0].path, "%s/reports/testoutput.csv" % (blobUrl))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This saves one csv file into the data lake, but it doesn't save it under the name specified.  It still ignores the file name and only writes to a directory name with a file of "part-00000-tid....".  After doing some further research I don't think it's possible to save to the data lake with a specific file name.  Which seems bizarre to me still.

Comment: If you're going to go this route, you should use `.coalesce(1)` instead of `.repartition(1)` to reduce data movement between nodes. Repartition will perform a full shuffle of the data to all nodes before reducing it to a single partition.

Comment: @DavidP You are 100% right. I will change the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand for your needs correctly, you just want to write the Spark DataFrame data to a single csv file named `testoutput.csv` into Azure Data Lake, not a directory named `testoutput.csv` with some partition files.

So you can not directly realize it via use these Spark functions like `DataFrameWriter.save`, because actually the dataframe writer writes data to HDFS based on Azure Data Lake. The HDFS persists data as a directory named yours and some partition files. Please see some documents about HDFS like [`The Hadoop FileSystem API Definition`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/index.html) to know it.

Then, per my experience, you can try to use Azure Data Lake SDK for Jave within your Scala program to directly write data from DataFrame to Azure Data Lake as a single file. And you can refer to some samples https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=data-lake&type=&language=java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df_join.to_csv('/dbfs/mnt/....../df.csv', sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```